# ARM warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for this architecture

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, arm

When compiling certain cpp files for my project I'm getting warnings like this

```
Compile++ arm    : MYAPP <= myfile.cpp
/tmp/cc53K5MQ.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc53K5MQ.s:887: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for this architecture
```

However, there's no any line number given in this warning so I don't know where to look at.

Do you have any idea why I'm getting this warning?

Comment: @zapi But that's line seems to be from a generated *.s assembler file not from my cpp file, I don't have a line 887

Comment: Ah sry, a generated file. https://github.com/Neverlord/libcppa/issues/13 could be the same reason.

Comment: @zapl Thanks, yes looks like it's the same reason because I'm using std::atomic too.

Comment: gcc myfile.cpp -S -c should produce myfile.s which contains the assembly.

Answer (score 6):

The `swp{b}` instruction is deprecated in ARMv6 and above.  Worse, it isn't supported *at all* in ARMv7 and is fixed up in the illegal instruction trap in the Linux kernel - at some runtime cost.   Your compiler should absolutely not be generating it.

I've seen this problem too with the CodeSourcery compiler.  The code generator phase emits `swp{b}` instructions, yet the assembler knows full well that they aren't supported for your target architecture.   This rather implies you have the correct target architecture specified on the command-line.

I fixed the problem by upgrading to a newer version of GCC.

Comment: Thanks, I got this warning using distcc cross compile.  The remote compiler was picking the wrong arch, so I fixed it by explicitly specifying the arch I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Use `--save-temps` to have GCC not delete the generated files.

Comment: Note that this won't fix the original problem, it will just make the .s file available so you can look at the assembly it's complaining about.